# Unknown command undefined when compiling Sass in browser with Sass.js

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I get `{line: 0, message: "Unknown command undefined"}` in console when trying to compile the Sass code using [sass.js](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/)

```html
<html>
<body></body>
<script src="dist/sass.js"></script>
<script>
  var sass = new Sass();
  var scss = '$someVar: 123px; .some-selector { width: $someVar; }';
  sass.compile(scss, function callback(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
</script>
</html>
```

I've traced the error back to sass.worker.js:

```js
var method = methods[event.data.command] || Sass[event.data.command];

if (!method) {
  return done({
    line: 0,
    message: "Unknown command " + event.action,
  });
}

method.apply(Sass, (event.data.args || []).concat([done]));
```

I can't find anyone else experiencing this error so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the non-compiled sass.worker in [src](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/blob/master/src/sass.worker.js) rather than [dist](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/blob/master/dist/sass.worker.js), even though it was in my dist folder